# Why does this SVG document not open correctly in Adobe Illustrator (latest version of creative cloud)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have an SVG file called `gear.svg` with the following contents:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 56 56"><defs/><path d="M25.45 14.84a.67.67 0 01.49.14.69.69 0 01.24.45.66.66 0 01-.48.71 13.09 13.09 0 00-9.36 9.38.77.77 0 01-.94.54.76.76 0 01-.55-.83 12.19 12.19 0 0110.6-10.39zm-5.54 10a8.36 8.36 0 019.62-5.38 8.3 8.3 0 014.29 13.91l-.08.07a.68.68 0 01-.92-1 6.84 6.84 0 00.26-8.81 6.64 6.64 0 00-11.44 1.83 6.59 6.59 0 000 4.59 6.79 6.79 0 007.58 4.3.76.76 0 01.32 1.48 8.32 8.32 0 01-9.67-11zM28.8 8.68h-2v.13l-.21 1.11-.22 1.12a1.85 1.85 0 01-1.49 1.49 16.66 16.66 0 00-2.07.56 15.39 15.39 0 00-2 .85c-.32.16-.63.33-.94.52l-.45.28-.23.15a2 2 0 01-.46.23 1.73 1.73 0 01-1.1 0 2 2 0 01-.51-.23l-.24-.16-1-.62-.83-.55L13.61 15l.07.1.63 1 .63 1a1.91 1.91 0 010 2.1 14.24 14.24 0 00-1.07 1.8 13.9 13.9 0 00-.8 2c-.11.3-.21.65-.3 1l-.08.5-.06.26a1.82 1.82 0 01-.16.5 1.91 1.91 0 01-.77.82 1.76 1.76 0 01-.54.2l-.28.06-1.11.23-1 .19v2l.15.05L10 29l1.12.23a1.91 1.91 0 011.47 1.5A16.23 16.23 0 0014 34.81c.16.32.33.63.52.94l.25.46.23.22a2.28 2.28 0 01.23.47 1.87 1.87 0 010 1.1 2.38 2.38 0 01-.24.51l-.16.24-.63 1-.55.82 1.41 1.5.11-.07 1-.62.95-.63a1.83 1.83 0 012.05 0 17.21 17.21 0 001.89 1 17.42 17.42 0 002 .81c.3.11.65.21 1 .3l.52.12.27.06a1.6 1.6 0 01.48.16 1.78 1.78 0 01.78.73 2.23 2.23 0 01.19.51l.06.29.3 1.08.19 1a.1.1 0 00.09.06h2v-.14l.21-1.15.23-1.12a1.78 1.78 0 011.42-1.39 14.94 14.94 0 002.09-.55 14.59 14.59 0 002-.84 7.8 7.8 0 001-.52l.46-.28.22-.15a1.81 1.81 0 01.44-.22 1.7 1.7 0 011 0 1.49 1.49 0 01.48.22l.23.15 1 .63.83.53a.17.17 0 00.17 0l1.45-1.45a.17.17 0 000-.1l-.07-.11-1.24-2a1.69 1.69 0 010-1.9 15.69 15.69 0 001.93-3.89c.11-.3.21-.65.3-1l.13-.53.06-.26a1.41 1.41 0 01.14-.44 1.59 1.59 0 01.67-.71 2.07 2.07 0 01.47-.18h.28l1.16-.25 1-.2a.29.29 0 00.13-.3H47v-2.06a.1.1 0 000-.05h-.15l-1.11-.22-1.12-.22a1.77 1.77 0 01-1.36-1.39 14.5 14.5 0 00-.64-2.16 14.13 14.13 0 00-.85-2c-.16-.32-.34-.64-.53-.95l-.28-.45-.17-.22a1.57 1.57 0 01-.23-1.44 1.45 1.45 0 01.22-.49l.15-.24.63-.95.55-.84a.15.15 0 000-.13l-1.44-1.42h-.09l-.11.07-1 .64-.94.63a1.86 1.86 0 01-2 0 16 16 0 00-3.87-1.88c-.3-.11-.65-.2-1-.29l-.52-.12-.27-.06a1.92 1.92 0 01-.48-.15 1.88 1.88 0 01-.79-.74 1.93 1.93 0 01-.2-.52v-.28l-.4-1.1-.2-1zm.13-1.8a1.82 1.82 0 011.7 1.18 1.12 1.12 0 01.08.26v.15l.06.28.1.61.22 1.11.06.28h.06l.22.19.58.14c.39.1.78.21 1.16.33a18.28 18.28 0 012.21.9 16.39 16.39 0 012.07 1.2h.12l1-.62 1-.63.14-.09.23-.12a1.82 1.82 0 01.52-.14 1.75 1.75 0 011 .21 2.07 2.07 0 01.42.31l.2.2.4.41.8.81a1.79 1.79 0 01.36 2 1.71 1.71 0 01-.13.23l-.08.13-.16.23-.32.48-.63.94-.16.23v.14l.16.25.31.51a7.3 7.3 0 01.58 1 17 17 0 01.92 2.2 16.58 16.58 0 01.61 2.3c0 .15.06.15.12.15l1.12.23 1.11.23h.16l.24.07a2 2 0 01.45.26 1.72 1.72 0 01.57.85 1.84 1.84 0 01-.07.47v2.07h-.04a1.63 1.63 0 01-1 1.51l-.23.07H47l-.28.06-.55.12-1.12.23-.27.06h-.07a.31.31 0 00-.09.11.17.17 0 000 .1l-.06.29-.13.58c-.09.39-.2.77-.32 1.15a17.33 17.33 0 01-2 4.27.21.21 0 000 .24l.64.94.52 1 .09.14a.94.94 0 01.12.22 1.78 1.78 0 01.14.5 1.75 1.75 0 01-.19 1 2.1 2.1 0 01-.31.41l-.2.2-.4.41-.79.81a1.73 1.73 0 01-1.94.36 1.71 1.71 0 01-.23-.13l-.13-.08-.24-.16-.47-.31-1-.62-.24-.16h-.14l-.25.17-.51.31a10.54 10.54 0 01-1 .59 17.68 17.68 0 01-2.2.93 18.18 18.18 0 01-2.3.63c-.12 0-.12.09-.12.09l-.22 1.12-.15 1.02v.16a2.58 2.58 0 01-.08.26 2.13 2.13 0 01-.27.46 1.77 1.77 0 01-.88.59 1.82 1.82 0 01-.52.08h-2a1.77 1.77 0 01-1.67-1.16.79.79 0 01-.08-.26V47l-.09-.25-.11-.56-.23-1.11-.06-.28h-.06l-.3-.06-.58-.14c-.39-.09-.77-.2-1.15-.32a17.31 17.31 0 01-4.3-2.08h-.09l-.95.63-1 .63-.13.09-.24.13a2 2 0 01-.54.14 1.89 1.89 0 01-1.07-.2 1.76 1.76 0 01-.43-.33l-.2-.2-.41-.4-.8-.8a1.84 1.84 0 01-.35-2.06c0-.08.13-.16.13-.24l.08-.13.16-.24.31-.47.63-1 .13-.35-.51-.8a8.51 8.51 0 01-.59-1 17.74 17.74 0 01-.94-2.2 19 19 0 01-.63-2.32l-1.12-.26-1.11-.22h-.16a1.22 1.22 0 01-.27-.09A1.81 1.81 0 017 29.3a1.75 1.75 0 01-.08-.55v-2A1.89 1.89 0 018.13 25l.28-.08h.15l.27-.05.56-.12 1.12-.25.26-.05.23-1c.1-.39.21-.77.34-1.16a17.32 17.32 0 012.1-4.3l-.62-1-.63-.95-.09-.04c0-.08-.13-.17-.13-.25a1.9 1.9 0 01.03-1.63 1.41 1.41 0 01.33-.44l.2-.2.4-.4.81-.81a1.84 1.84 0 012.19-.4 2 2 0 01.25.14l.13.08.23.16.48.32.94.63.24.15.25-.16.51-.32 1-.58a19.48 19.48 0 012.21-.93 16.85 16.85 0 012.32-.61h.07l.18-1.17.37-1.11v-.16a1.38 1.38 0 01.11-.31 1.47 1.47 0 01.27-.47A1.72 1.72 0 0126.4 7a1.89 1.89 0 01.53-.08z"/></svg>
```

When I try opening this in Illustrator, I get the following blank artboard:

[image]

Why isn't the SVG being imported as expected?

You can view the [SVG here](https://jsfiddle.net/t8smayrv/) to verify that it does display properly in a browser.

Comment: Too big? Maybe it does not fit illudtrators max size.

Comment: I doubt it since the contents of the file isn’t large at all (see above) and I’ve definitely used much larger svgs in the past

Comment: Try to use Figma as mediator and then open new svg in AI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the root issue was, but one workaround was to import the file to https://vecta.io/ (must create a free account first) and then to export an SVG from there.

The exported SVG was:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1056" height="816"  stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M409.1344 349.2054a1.795 1.795 0 0 1 1.3125.375 1.848 1.848 0 0 1 .6429 1.2054 1.768 1.768 0 0 1-1.2858 1.9017c-12.292 3.214-21.8837 12.8262-25.0714 25.125-.3002 1.0914-1.4238 1.7369-2.5178 1.4465-.9757-.2714-1.6035-1.2189-1.4733-2.2232 2.0747-14.6337 13.7206-26.0489 28.3929-27.8304zm-14.8393 26.7857c3.7582-10.5874 14.7798-16.7512 25.7679-14.4107 7.9537 1.6311 14.3857 7.4683 16.7785 15.2268s.3658 16.2045-5.2875 22.0321l-.2142.1875c-.7455.6307-1.8557.5613-2.5169-.1573s-.6379-1.8308.0526-2.5212c5.9446-6.6482 6.2387-16.6111.6964-23.5983-3.9934-5.0475-10.4022-7.5437-16.7575-6.527a17.786 17.786 0 0 0-13.8854 11.4288c-1.4733 3.9658-1.4733 8.3289 0 12.2947 3.0864 8.2489 11.6398 13.101 20.3036 11.5178a2.036 2.036 0 0 1 .8572 3.9643c-7.9842 1.8407-16.3344-.8483-21.7442-7.0021s-7.0063-14.7797-4.1576-22.4622zm23.8125-43.2857h-5.3571v.3482l-.5625 2.9732-.5893 3c-.3687 2.0321-1.959 3.6224-3.9911 3.9911-1.8784.3804-3.7305.8815-5.5446 1.5-1.8371.6318-3.6273 1.3926-5.3571 2.2768-.8572.4286-1.6875.8839-2.5179 1.3928l-1.2054.75-.6161.4018c-.3824.2576-.7966.4646-1.2321.6161-.956.3206-1.9904.3206-2.9464 0a5.353 5.353 0 0 1-1.3661-.6161l-.6429-.4285-2.6785-1.6608-2.2232-1.4732-3.8572 3.8572.1875.2678 3.375 5.3572a5.116 5.116 0 0 1 0 5.625c-1.0724 1.5346-2.0303 3.1461-2.8661 4.8214a37.251 37.251 0 0 0-2.1428 5.3571c-.2947.8036-.5625 1.7411-.8036 2.6786l-.2142 1.3393-.1608.6964c-.0774.4648-.2217.916-.4286 1.3393a5.115 5.115 0 0 1-2.0625 2.1964 4.715 4.715 0 0 1-1.4464.5358l-.75.1607-2.9732.616-2.6785.509v5.3571l.4017.1339 2.8929.509 3 .616c1.9971.4328 3.5452 2.0125 3.9375 4.0179a43.47 43.47 0 0 0 3.7768 10.9286c.4286.8571.8839 1.6875 1.3928 2.5178l.6697 1.2322.6161.5893c.2529.3946.4597.817.616 1.2589a5.007 5.007 0 0 1 0 2.9464 6.37 6.37 0 0 1-.6429 1.3661l-.4285.6428-1.6875 2.6786-1.4732 2.1964 3.7767 4.0179.2947-.1875 2.6786-1.6607 2.5446-1.6875a4.902 4.902 0 0 1 5.4911 0 46.104 46.104 0 0 0 5.0625 2.6786 46.659 46.659 0 0 0 5.3571 2.1696c.8036.2946 1.7411.5625 2.6786.8036l1.3928.3214.7233.1607c.4486.0738.8825.2185 1.2857.4286a4.768 4.768 0 0 1 2.0893 1.9553c.2247.433.3957.8917.5089 1.3661l.1607.7768.8036 2.8929.5089 2.6785c.0419.0962.1362.159.2411.1607h5.3571v-.375l.5625-3.0803.6161-3a4.768 4.768 0 0 1 3.8036-3.7232 40.035 40.035 0 0 0 5.5982-1.4732c1.839-.616 3.6297-1.3682 5.3571-2.25.9253-.3991 1.8205-.8646 2.6786-1.3929l1.2322-.75.5892-.4018c.3643-.2491.7607-.4474 1.1786-.5893.8727-.2685 1.8059-.2685 2.6786 0 .4602.1184.8956.318 1.2857.5893l.616.4018 2.6786 1.6875 2.2233 1.4196a.455.455 0 0 0 .4553 0l3.8839-3.8839a.456.456 0 0 0 0-.2678l-.1875-.2947-3.3214-5.3571c-1.0438-1.5359-1.0438-3.5535 0-5.0893 2.1979-3.2168 3.9377-6.7236 5.1697-10.4197.2946-.8035.5625-1.741.8035-2.6785l.3482-1.4197.1608-.6964c.0593-.4108.186-.8089.375-1.1786.384-.8064 1.0118-1.4717 1.7946-1.9018a5.545 5.545 0 0 1 1.2589-.4821h.75l3.1071-.6696 2.6786-.5358a.777.777 0 0 0 .3483-.8035h-.3483v-5.5179c.0113-.0439.0113-.09 0-.1339h-.4017l-2.9733-.5893-3-.5893a4.741 4.741 0 0 1-3.6428-3.7232c-.4206-1.9701-.9937-3.9045-1.7143-5.7857a37.847 37.847 0 0 0-2.2768-5.3572c-.4286-.8571-.9107-1.7142-1.4197-2.5446l-.75-1.2054-.4553-.5892c-.8262-1.1066-1.0565-2.5483-.6161-3.8572.113-.4704.3129-.9155.5893-1.3125l.4018-.6428 1.6875-2.5447 1.4732-2.25a.402.402 0 0 0 0-.3482l-3.8571-3.8036h-.2411l-.2947.1875-2.6785 1.7143-2.5179 1.6875a4.982 4.982 0 0 1-5.3571 0 42.858 42.858 0 0 0-10.3661-5.0357c-.8035-.2946-1.741-.5357-2.6785-.7768l-1.3929-.3214-.7232-.1607c-.4444-.077-.8766-.2121-1.2858-.4018a5.036 5.036 0 0 1-2.116-1.9822 5.167 5.167 0 0 1-.5357-1.3928v-.75l-1.0714-2.9464-.5358-2.6786zm.3483-4.8214c2.0274.0042 3.8405 1.2628 4.5535 3.1607a3.003 3.003 0 0 1 .2143.6964v.4018l.1607.75.2679 1.6339.5892 2.9732.1608.75h.1607l.5893.509 1.5536.375c1.0446.2678 2.0892.5625 3.1071.8839a48.973 48.973 0 0 1 5.9196 2.4107c1.9241.935 3.7772 2.0092 5.5447 3.2143h.3214l2.6786-1.6607 2.6786-1.6875.375-.2411.616-.3214a4.873 4.873 0 0 1 1.3929-.375 4.688 4.688 0 0 1 2.6786.5625c.4085.2282.7865.5072 1.125.8303l.5356.5358 1.0715 1.0982 2.1429 2.1696a4.795 4.795 0 0 1 .9642 5.3572c-.1.214-.2164.42-.3482.616l-.2143.3482-.4286.6161-.8571 1.2857-1.6875 2.5179-.4285.6161v.375l.4285.6696.8304 1.3661c.5879.8503 1.1073 1.746 1.5536 2.6785a45.556 45.556 0 0 1 2.4642 5.8929c.6915 2.0118 1.2375 4.0707 1.6339 6.1607 0 .4018.1608.4018.3215.4018l3 .6161 2.9732.616h.4286l.6428.1875a5.359 5.359 0 0 1 1.2054.6965c.7282.5864 1.2607 1.3805 1.5268 2.2768-.0078.426-.0708.8491-.1875 1.2589v5.5446h-.1072a4.366 4.366 0 0 1-2.6786 4.0447l-.616.1875h-.4554l-.75.1607-1.4732.3214-3 .6161-.7232.1607h-.1875a.832.832 0 0 0-.2411.2946.455.455 0 0 0 0 .2679l-.1607.7768-.3482 1.5536c-.2411 1.0446-.5357 2.0625-.8572 3.0803a46.413 46.413 0 0 1-5.3571 11.4375c-.1345.1932-.1345.4497 0 .6429l1.7143 2.5178 1.3928 2.6786.2411.375a2.514 2.514 0 0 1 .3214.5893 4.765 4.765 0 0 1 .375 1.3393c.0996.9235-.0776 1.8558-.5089 2.6785a5.624 5.624 0 0 1-.8303 1.0983l-.5358.5357-3.1875 3.2678a4.634 4.634 0 0 1-5.1964.9643 4.588 4.588 0 0 1-.6161-.3482l-.3481-.2143-.6429-.4286-1.259-.8303-2.6785-1.6607-.6429-.4286h-.375l-.6696.4554-1.3661.8303c-.8631.5756-1.7574 1.1032-2.6785 1.5804a47.353 47.353 0 0 1-5.8929 2.491 48.681 48.681 0 0 1-6.1607 1.6875c-.3214 0-.3214.2411-.3214.2411l-.5894 3-.4017 2.7322v.4285a6.87 6.87 0 0 1-.2143.6964 5.71 5.71 0 0 1-.7232 1.2322c-.606.7551-1.4285 1.3066-2.3572 1.5804a4.872 4.872 0 0 1-1.3928.2142h-5.3572a4.741 4.741 0 0 1-4.4732-3.1071c-.1112-.218-.1837-.4536-.2143-.6964v-.3482l-.2411-.6697-.2946-1.5-.616-2.9732-.1608-.75h-.1607l-.8035-.1607-1.5536-.375c-1.0447-.2411-2.0625-.5357-3.0804-.8572a46.366 46.366 0 0 1-11.5179-5.5714h-.241l-2.5446 1.6875-2.6786 1.6875-.3483.2411-.6428.3482a5.355 5.355 0 0 1-1.4464.375 5.062 5.062 0 0 1-2.8661-.5357 4.715 4.715 0 0 1-1.1518-.8839l-.5357-.5358-1.0982-1.0714-2.1429-2.1428a4.929 4.929 0 0 1-.9375-5.5179c0-.2143.3483-.4286.3483-.6429l.2142-.3482.4286-.6428.8303-1.259 1.6875-2.6785.3483-.9375-1.3661-2.1429c-.5872-.8558-1.1151-1.7508-1.5803-2.6786a47.504 47.504 0 0 1-2.5179-5.8928 50.882 50.882 0 0 1-1.6875-6.2143l-3-.6964-2.9732-.5893h-.4286c-.2497-.0519-.4923-.1328-.7232-.2411-1.4524-.5428-2.5575-1.7474-2.9732-3.2411a4.689 4.689 0 0 1-.2143-1.4732v-5.3571c.0148-2.08 1.3003-3.9392 3.241-4.6875l.75-.2143h.4019l.7231-.1339 1.5-.3215 3-.6696.6965-.1339.616-2.6786c.2679-1.0446.5625-2.0625.9108-3.1071 1.333-4.0811 3.226-7.9573 5.625-11.5179l-1.6608-2.6786-1.6875-2.5446-.241-.1072c0-.2142-.3482-.4553-.3482-.6696-.6306-1.3935-.6012-2.9968.0803-4.3661.2145-.4471.5148-.8475.8839-1.1785l3.7769-3.7768a4.929 4.929 0 0 1 5.866-1.0715 5.367 5.367 0 0 1 .6696.375l.3483.2143.6161.4286 1.2856.8571 2.5179 1.6875.6429.4018.6696-.4285 1.3661-.8572 2.6785-1.5536c1.9203-.9511 3.8972-1.783 5.9197-2.491 2.03-.6916 4.1067-1.2376 6.2143-1.634h.1875l.4821-3.1339.9911-2.9732v-.4286c.0648-.2875.1637-.5663.2947-.8303.1608-.4609.4061-.8878.7231-1.259.6442-.7163 1.4966-1.2129 2.4375-1.4196.4607-.1385.9387-.2106 1.4197-.2143z" stroke="none" fill="#000" fill-rule="nonzero"/></svg>
```

And this opened up nicely in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: [File comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L72Q.png) shows the XML was *completely* rewritten. Are you affiliated with vecta.io?

Comment: I'm not at all affiliated... just found [this blog post](https://vecta.io/blog/5-most-common-problems-faced-by-svg-users) and decided to give it a shot. Worked, but I don't know if there is a simpler way to get Illustrator to open the original SVG file

Comment: Original file crashes AI here.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with Illustrator not opening it. The first example opens in Inskcape just fine, although the cog is a bit wonky at some parts.  I'd simply recreate it. Not worth fixing.

Comment: @Scott Even if the original file crashes AI, it works just fine in the browser, which is why I'm confused.